# Replace characters (&amp) in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to use the inbuilt oracle function to replace '&amp' with &. I wrote two functions below but it's not working for me. On running these two in sql developer tool its asking me for input. My requirement is to replace html entities.

`select REPLACE('&amp;amp;', '&amp;', '&') from DUAL;`
`select regexp_replace('&amp;amp;', '&amp;', '&') from DUAL;`

Could any one please tell me what's wrong I am doing?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should probably be marked as a duplicate, but you need to add this to your script

`SET SCAN OFF` - that tells us to ignore the & which is used for replacing text when running code in SQLPlus

[image]

Once you have that disabled, you can run the queries one at a time with data grids (the first execution mode) or as sqlplus scripts (the second execution mode).

Comment: hi thanks for your answer. Another question is do I write this (SET SCAN OFF) at top if I'm writing new custom defined function?

Comment: your function will run in the database itself, so SET commands do not come into play, this is a CLIENT side application thing, not the database

Answer (score 0):

You should execute `set define off` before executing your query to suppress processing of substitution variables which start by &.

The command `set define off` will stay active until you enter `set define on` on your sqlplus session or sql developer worksheet.

thatjeffsmith answer was right but `set scan off` is tagged obsolete by Oracle. Anyway, it still work.